# How to reset the configurations of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress for site  developement and i have changed some settings like Url  in dashboard with this i am not able to login ? how to recover old settings

Comment: I am at early stage of development, I was playing and getting familiar with word-press, Suddenly this happned

Comment: Have you tried to look at the config table in the database? You can manually edit the URL in that table without accessing the dashboard.

Comment: your best bet is to reinstall

Comment: Thanks Vlad i have created new DB and edited Con-fig file now its working

Comment: URL always must to point exactly where your wp is stored. Also make sure the permalinks are working.